How to execute a function before a react native app is hot reloaded
The React Native Metro workflow features a 'r' reload command at the CLI that reloads the application. It does this in such a way that the componentWillUnmount() process is not invoked like a normal React shutdown in a web browser.
I need a chance to close any resources acquired, like a WebSocket or Audio player.
Related questions that go nowhere, or have no answers
[1] How to execute a function just before a react native app is hot reloaded
[2] How to run a JS funktion before Metro replaces my React Native JS code via "Reload"
Hoping to re-spark this discussion as it's quite hard to find related threads specific to react-native.
I expect componentWillUnmount() to run, or, for there to be an exported function from ReactNative.DevSettings similar to onbeforeunload.

simply exit from your application in mobile/emulator then open it again. no data loss

That's not what I've asked for. I want the react native Metro ecosystem to be a bit more robust to having to force stop the app.
